# What is going wrong? Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: xml, joomla, installation

I have a question. I am trying to install the mijoshop plugin into my joomla 3.1.1 with extension manager, but i get the following message:

```
**Warning: Failed to move file!
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/vol14_1/byethost14.com/b14_13580600/htdocs/tmp/install_521be9ec83fd8
JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/vol14_1/byethost14.com/b14_13580600/htdocs/tmp/install_521be9ec83fd8
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/vol14_1/byethost14.com/b14_13580600/htdocs/tmp/install_521be9ec83fd8
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file**



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install version="3.0" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
<name>System - MijoShop jQuery</name>
<author>Mijosoft LLC</author>
<creationDate>October 2012</creationDate>
<authorEmail>info@mijosoft.com</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>http://mijosoft.com</authorUrl>
<copyright>Copyright (C) Mijosoft LLC, mijosoft.com</copyright>
<license>GNU/GPL, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html</license>
<version>1.2.0</version>
<description><![CDATA[<b><font color="red">DON'T FORGET TO PUBLISH THE PLUGIN.</font></b>]]></description>
<files>
    <filename plugin="mijoshopjquery">mijoshopjquery.php</filename>
    <folder>mijoshopjquery</folder>
</files>

<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="only_mijoshop" type="radio" default="1" label="Only if MijoShop" description="Load the following libraries only viewing any MijoShop module or page.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_ui" type="radio" default="1" label="Load jQuery UI" description="Load UI library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_cookie" type="radio" default="1" label="Load Cookie" description="Load Cookie library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_colorbox" type="radio" default="1" label="Load Colorbox" description="Load Colorbox library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_cycle" type="radio" default="1" label="Load Cycle" description="Load Cycle library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_jcarousel" type="radio" default="1" label="Load jCarousel" description="Load jCarousel library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
            <field name="load_nivo_slider" type="radio" default="1" label="Load Nivo Slider" description="Load Nivo Slider library of jQuery.">
                <option value="0">No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: try changing `<install ....` to `<extension ....` and also add `</extension>` to the end of the file

Comment: Make sure the path for your `tmp` path is set correctly